# How do I restrict a List View to certain groups?

Tags: permissions, list-view

When creating a custom list view, there's the option to restrict visibility to certain groups of users, based on Roles, Public Group Membership, Portal Roles, etc.

However, list views created in this way are still visible to users that are not in these groups/roles.  They also don't seem to have the Manage Public List Views permission either, so I'm at a loss as to why they can see them.

Anyone able to clarify why this would be?

Comment: What kind of profile do these users have?

Comment: Various  custom profiles, non sysadmin.

Comment: Do these users have modify all data or view all data permissions enabled?

Comment: Will check when back at work tomorrow - IP restrictions ;-)

Comment: It was indeed a rogue permisison set giving them View All Data.  Those without it get the expected behaviour.  Thanks for helping me get past this blind spot :-)